# JavaScript not showing text area on change of select

Tags: javascript, html

```
function otherShow() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("hideme");
    var x = document.forms.myForm.other_trade.value;
    if (x == "other") {
        textarea.style.display = 'block';
    }else {
        textarea.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This is my JavaScript code that is supposed to hide the text area that holds the `ID=hideme` and the action is triggered `onchange="otherShow();"`

```
<select name="trade" required="required" class="inputbox" id="trade" onchange="otherShow();">
<option value="" selected="selected"> Select one... </option>
<option value="" disabled="disabled">  ----------------------   </option>
<option value="General Labourer">Option1</option> 
.......
</select>
```

The above is the Select and below is the Textarea

```
<textarea cols="36" rows="6" class="inputbox" id="hideme" name="other_trade"></textarea>
```

In the end of the Select i have a

```
<option value="Other"> Other </other>
```

I want to show the Text area when the Other is selected. Please help I think the loginc is correct but it just do not work when I change it to some value it hides the text area, but do not change it...

Comment: Where is ending tag of other option? <option value="Other"> Other </option>

Comment: Based on the comment you left on the other answer, unless differentiating casing is of some importance I would do a compare similar to this:  `x.toUpperCase() === 'OTHER'`. Can save you a lot of those time consuming issues. Also, seeing that casing was your issue, you should propably answer your own question and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of the select box is `trade` not `other_trade`:

```
var x = document.forms.myForm.trade.value;
```

or :

```
var x = this.value;
```

instead of :

```
var x = document.forms.myForm.other_trade.value;
```

Comment: OMG... I feel like an Idiot.. But this do not help .. It is still the same

Comment: Thank you Just done it you ware of much help cu'z of thye other_trade -> trade replacement

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("trade").onchange=function() {
    var textarea = this.form.other_trade;
    textarea.style.display=(this.value=="Other")?"block":"none";
  }
}
```

Comment: might be useful but I solved it The problem was that the value in the if is "other" and the actual value is "Other".... thanks anyway that was fast..

Comment: Not just useful, but unobtrusive and simpler

Answer (score 1):

Replace **other** to **Other** in your javascript show/hide condition, because it's compare case sensative